# Ember uploader authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, devise

I am trying to upload an image to a rails API from an ember app. I have installed the ember uploader addon and my URL is correct (works perfectly through postman), but I am having problems with authentication.

The app itself is set up with devise and the routes all have authenticatedRouteMixin and the adaptors have the dataAdaptorMixin which automatically take care of the authentication.

I am struggling to inject authentication into the the call to the API. My call to the API currently looks like this. An extra argument can go at (files[0],{extraArgument}) but not sure if this is where I should be putting authentication details or how to access them.

```
export default EmberUploader.FileField.extend({

  filesDidChange: function(files) {
    const uploader = EmberUploader.Uploader.create({
      url: this.get('url'),
      method: 'PUT',


    });

    if (!Ember.isEmpty(files)) {
      data with the upload
      uploader.upload(files[0]);
    }
  }
});
```

PS. An additional problem I have is that the URL needs to be supplied however I need to be supplying the id of the models so it knows where to go, any suggestions on how to dynamically make the URL would also be appreciated.

Comment: Is that your JS (or Coffeescript) we're looking at? Authentication should *always* be done on the server-side, so don't try adding auth to your JS.

Comment: it is the JS from ember uploader add on. https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader    I need to send up to the server for it to be authenticated right? like headers or something?

Comment: Oh, you're doing the client side. Okay, so you need to give the server something like a username and password? To know exactly what you need to send, we need to see the server auth code.

Comment: I believe I need to supply the headers containing access-token, client and uid. I am just unsure of how to inject these into this part as they already exist within the app. I